# How To Run Script In Linux At Startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to run a script at startup, for that i added a script in Init.d and created a link using command "update-rc.d script_name defaults"
But when i restart the system i got only black screen. What can be the fault i am facing?

```
#!/bin/sh
#/etc/init.d/hello.sh
#
clear
echo "Hello $USER"
echo "Today is \c ";date
echo "Number of user login : \c" ; who | wc -l
echo "Calendar"
cal
```

Comment: What kind of script.. Can't it just crontab with @reboot

Comment: I didn't tried crontab yet but I am trying to print some text on display as my system start, I loaded script in init.d and created link as per above link but still something missing

Answer (score 0):

As the SysV has been replaced by Upstart you should create a Upstart script for your task.

At first create a file in `/etc/init/` directory, the filename must end in `.conf`. So, lets say the filename in your case is `check_script.conf`.

For your case the `check_script.conf` should have the following entries:

```
description  'Running script_name at startup'

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

script
    exec /full/path/to/script_name
end script
```

Comment: I tried your idea but still something missing

Comment: Please add the script you want to run to your original question..

Comment: i attach the script which i'm trying to run on startup

Comment: Should we have to mention only one run level ?

Comment: @AKASH: No, multiple is Ok.

Comment: On my system current run level is 2 and when I configure it to be 3 then I got same black screen